# Merging multiple nodes in one node in node-red

Tags: node.js, node-red

This question was probably asked before (I can't find it anywhere).

Is it possible to merge multiple nodes in node-red [image: multiple nodes]

To some sort of a "black-box" one node, that has input and output, but users cannot see what's inside ?

[image: one black box]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Node-RED lets you create 'Subflows' that are a collection of nodes collapsed into a single node in the palette.

https://nodered.org/docs/user-guide/editor/workspace/subflows

Users can still open up the subflow to see inside it.

With the latest release, we also now support turning a subflow into an npm module that can be published and installed by users. In that scenario, the user *cannot* see inside the subflow as it appears just like any other node in the flow. However they would still be able to access the JSON definition of the subflow by looking inside the npm module.

https://nodered.org/blog/2021/04/08/version-1-3-released#npm-packaged-subflows